# converting one JSON structure into another JSON structure

Tags: json, rest

The client side expects JSON string in the below format

```
descriptions": [
      {
        "lang": "string",
        "size": "string",
        "text": "string",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
```

, but the received JSON is a bit different - like below

```
"descriptions":{
  "desc":[
{
      "size":string,
      "lang":"string",
      "type":"string",
      "content":"string"
    }
  ]
},
```

Is there anyway to ignore the "desc" part - for eg. using a JSON annotation ? 
Context:  I am passing this JSON through a REST API call and it will be automatically converted to a Java object at the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
descriptions = descriptions.desc;
```

will do.

Comment: I tried this - but the model object I am using is referred in many places( for eg. to retrieve data from Mongo DB and store) - so when I use    
    @JsonProperty("descriptions.desc")
     List<Desc> descriptions = new ArrayList<>(); and try to use this model class, it gives me this error "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not construct instance of <model>"

Answer (score 0):

You just construct the object you need:

```
var clientDescriptions = descriptions.desc.map(function(d) {
   size: d.size,
   type: d.type,
   lang: d.lang,
   content: d.text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gson, it is possible to use custom JsonDeserializer / JsonSerializer for your Java model.  Your model object and API can then be cleanly implemented without having to deal with the different json structures.

Comment: Hey Pete, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider improving this answer with more details and possibly a code snippet to explain your solution.

Answer (score -1):

In my personal experience, the **backend has a bug and must be solved**, it mustn't be sending malformed data.In the long run it is the best solution.